# Have all prices end with cents in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using onedrive.live I have prices like so:

```
10.12 -- 10.12
9.75 -- 9.75
6.81 -- 6.81
5.46 -- 5.46
13.98 -- 13.98
24.67 -- 24.67
20.83 -- 20.83
34.08 -- 34.08
14.65 -- 14.65
8.03 -- 8.03
```

How can I edit this CSV file so all prices end with .25?

Ex: 8.03 --> 8.25

Comment: Are you wanting to round up to nearest quarter?

Comment: No, just have the numbers end exactly with .25, so if 4.99 should be 4.25

Comment: Have you tried importing the .csv into excel via VBA or anything yet? If so, can you put that code up - shouldn't be too difficult to modify it. A line or two based around split(cells(), ".",-1) should do it

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what VBA is, yes I import this to Excel online and I search for code to change the prices, but so far nothing is working. I'm very new to Excel, just learning it today

Comment: Oh, OK, so you have the stuff in an excel sheet?

Comment: Yes, and I think I know now how to work this out, I use `=ROUND(C6,0)+0.15` Is this right? However I can't do this on all cells at once, I have a lot of prices. How can I bulk edit them?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in an excel sheet, and presented as per above in col A of sheet.

in colB, formula as below:

```
=LEFT(B1,SEARCH(".",B1,1)-1)
```

in colC, formula as below:

```
=B1 & ".25"
```

So cell C1 would read 10.25

Then run the formula down for each line and you should have full output in col C.

edit: As you say you could split the text by the "--" on import, then rounddown(A1,0) then add 0.25

I don't know what way you've imported, so assumed a block of text.